# Error with model_name_ids method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Below is my controller code

```
class ProductComparisonController < ApplicationController

def product_vote
    if !session[:category_tracker]
        @categories = Category.where(:page_id => params[:page_id]).select(:id)
        session[:category_tracker]=@categories
        session[:step]=0
        session[:number_of_categories]=@categories.count
    end

    chosen_products = session[:category_tracker][session[:step]].chosen_product_ids
    @products = Product.where(:id => chosen_products).all
    session[:step] = session[:step] + 1

end
```

end

When I run this, it runs perfectly for the first instance of category. But then when the step value gets update and it has to fetch the 2nd value from the session variable it gives an error.

The error is: (Line 11)

undefined method `chosen_product_ids' for :@new_record:Symbol

Comment: Where are you storing your session? If it's the default cookie session, bear in mind you have *very* limited space.

Comment: what is there in `session[:category_tracker][session[:step]]` ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the Relation to an array of numbers to store in your session. And then fetch the object from the database based on the ID of the current step.

```
class ProductComparisonController < ApplicationController

  def product_vote
    if !session[:category_tracker]
      # No need to use instance variables here.
      categories = Category.where(:page_id => params[:page_id]).select(:id)
      # Iterate the categories extracting only the ids.
      # select(:id) does not do this.
      session[:category_tracker] = categories.map(&:id)
      session[:step] = 0
      session[:number_of_categories] = categories.count
    end

    # First fetch the category
    category = Category.find(session[:category_tracker][session[:step]])
    # Then call methods on it
    chosen_products = category.chosen_product_ids
    @products = Product.where(:id => chosen_products).all
    session[:step] += 1
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have understood what I was doing wrong here.

Comment: Also, I am little confused about why it was working correctly for the first time (i.e. it was fetching the chosen_product_ids) and not afterwards(i.e. for the rest of categories). Is it because of the limited space of the default cookie session as Dave Newton said?

Comment: It's because when you run the first time the information is held in memory. On every subsequent request it is actually being pulled from the session store.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing an ActiveRecord::Relation in the session instead of the actual array.

Try adding a .all to the end of your Category fetch

Comment: Also, once that is done, the code will be calling `chosen_product_ids` on a Fixnum, so the model will need to be loaded as well before assigning `chosen_products`.